# Why is my git 'tracked files' not showing up on my working directory? And How to move it back to my working directory

Tags: git

I have a folder and I did some renaming and rollback operations.
If I run `git ls-files`, it will show up like:

```
XinyuLi-MBP:CS1 xinyuli$ git ls-files
.gitignore
Lab01/README.md
Lab02/README.md
Lab03/README.md
README.md
```

The above is good and is also my latest commit.
However, what it is shown up on my working tree is like:

```
XinyuLi-MBP:CS1 xinyuli$ ls
Lab01           Lab02           README.md       lab03
```

Note that I rename my folder to `Lab03` from `lab03`, so the staged files is good.
However, this new folder `Lab03` is not shown up on my editor so I cannot see it. Additionally, even if I checkout lastest commit, `Lab03` still does not show up.

Can anyone tell me why is this? And How can I move this `Lab3` to my working directory so that I can review and edit it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `MBP` in your prompt suggests that you're using a MacBookPro, and hence macOS.  The default *file systems* on macOS are *case-preserving but case-insensitive*.  This means that if you create a file named `README.md`, such as the one that you have shown here, and then ask the operating system to open or create a file named `readme.md` or `ReadMe.md`, the OS uses the *existing* file named `README.md` instead.

This same rule applies to directory or folder names.  (Some people prefer the word *directory*, others prefer *folder;* both refer to the same thing: a sort of file of a container type, that contains further files.  Note that Git's index / staging-area, as seen with `git ls-files`, has no folders: it just has path names like `Lab01/README.md` that contain embedded slashes.  As a side effect, Git has to translate between its internal file names—which have these embedded slashes—and your OS's folder-and-file scheme.)

What all of this means is that you have, somehow—we don't know how; you'd have to find that out for yourself—created a folder named `lab03` in your working tree.  Any attempt to use the name `Lab03` simply refers back to this existing `lab03` folder.  Every time Git tries to use a name like `Lab03/README.md`, your operating system says to itself: *aha, you must mean you want me to create or update `lab03/README.md`, not `Lab03/README.md`*.  So Git can't do anything to fix the lowercse name.

*You* can, though:

```
XinyuLi-MBP:CS1 xinyuli$ mv lab03 Lab03
```

will deliver to your OS a command of the form: *rename the `lab03` folder to `Lab03`*.  Testing on my own macOS system shows that this works.

On some systems that do case-folding (not mine and probably not yours either) you might have to resort to two separate steps, as in:

```
mv lab03 tmp && mv tmp Lab03
```

so that the intermediate name doesn't case-folded-ly match either the initial or final names.  You'll see this general algorithm used for old Windows systems, for instance.

Comment: Thanks. The naming convention for MacOS is really helpful on this issue:)